# Is it possible to alert returned xml data from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to at least alert the data that is being returned as xml from this ajax request. Any ideas on how to accomplish? So its pulling the data from a url not an actual xml list, but it is being converted to xml. Also, is it possible for me to alert a specific node if I can get the data to alert?

```js
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: searchData.SiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });            
}
```

Comment: Put `alert(returnValue)` into your `processResult()` function

Comment: You will ofcourse need to adjust the variable name to suit whatever your `processResult()` is receiving

Comment: Still isnt working. I added var returnValue = "searchData.SiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"

Comment: As a side note, if you need it for debugging purposes, instead of alerting, in your ajax success parameter function, you could console.log(response) and inspect with F12 on your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution!

```
    alert(xData.responseXML);
    console.log(xData.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: searchData.SiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",

success:function(response){
     alert (response.responseText);
},


error:function(response){
     alert (response.responseText);

},
    });            
}
```

Try adding the success and error fields to your ajax call.

Per hina10531's suggestion, use this to alert the text held in the foo node:

```
alert ($(response).find ('foo').text ());
```

Comment: Good to suggest him the callbacks, but responseText should not be treated there. It could be the whole html codes of the page. Why don't you improve your answer by providing him the way to handle his returned XML and parse it to display a specific node value?

Comment: I tried pl0x suggestion, but I got an undefined alerted back because I am missing responsetext. Not sure what to set as responseText. Anyhow , can someone please show me how to alert one xml node from this ajax call?